# The route build/api/store-comment could not be found

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 10 API, the latest updated. Facing a route error on production, this code works fine on localhost. All other routes are working fine, I couldn't fine the reason. Please assist me, I have tried to clear the cache routes using "php artisan route:cache" but no impact. Am I doing something wrong here? This is the response:
[image: Data Response]

This is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Forms;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Helpers\Helper;
use App\Http\Requests\CommentStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\CommentResource;
use App\Jobs\AttachmentsJob;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
class SCRFController extends Controller
{
    public function storeComment(CommentStoreRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            if (auth()->check()) {
                $comment = new Comment($request->validated());
                auth()->user()->comments()->save($comment);
                //Attachments
                $attachments = [];
                $prefix = Str::lower(class_basename(Comment::class));
                if(null !== $request->file('attachments'))
                {
                    foreach($request->file('attachments') as $attachment)
                    {
                        $filename = $attachment->getClientOriginalName();
                        Storage::putFileAs('public/attachments/'.$prefix.'/'.$comment->id, $attachment, $filename, 'public');

                        $url = 'storage/attachments/'.$prefix.'/'.$comment->id.'/'.$attachment->getClientOriginalName();
                        $attachments[] = [
                            'attachable_id' => $comment->id,
                            'attachable_type' => Comment::class,
                            'filename' => $url
                        ];
                    }
                }
                if (!empty($attachments)) {
                    $job = new AttachmentsJob($attachments);
                    dispatch($job);
                }
                return new CommentResource($comment);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated'], 401);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 422);
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class CommentStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'scrf_id' => 'required|exists:scrf,id',
            'parent_id' => [
                'nullable',
                Rule::exists('comments', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('id', request()->input('parent_id'));
                }),
            ],
            'comment' => 'required|min:1|max:1000'
        ];
    }
}
?>

<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CommentResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => $this->user ? $this->user->only('id','name') : null,
            'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
            'comment' => $this->comment,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'replies' => CommentResource::collection($this->replies),
            'comment_attachments' => AttachmentResource::collection($this->attachments),
        ];
    }
}
?>
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['scrf_id', 'comment', 'parent_id'];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function scrf(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SCRF::class, 'scrf_id', 'id');
    }

    public function replies(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function attachables(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Attachment::class, 'attachable');
    }

    public function attachments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class, 'attachable_id', 'id');
    }
}
?>
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BusinessExpertController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DesignationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Forms\QualityAssuranceController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Forms\SCRFController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LocationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PermissionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RoleController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SectionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return new UserResource($request->user());
});
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified', 'cors']], function(){
    Route::post('store-comment', [SCRFController::class, 'storeComment']);
});
```

Comment: seems odd its adding `build` to the beginning of the path it is looking for a route for when that isn't the current path

Comment: To clear route you need to use  php artisan route:clear.   But you have mentioned php artisan route:cache. See if this is the issue.

Comment: @Ali `route:cache` calls `route:clear` first then rebuilds the cache

Comment: @lagbox thank you for letting me know. I didn’t know that before.

Comment: I tried to dd($route) here:

 "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php:31"

protected function handleMatchedRoute(Request $request, $route)
    {
        dd($route);
        if (! is_null($route)) {
            return $route->bind($request);
        }
    }
It shows null. Is it helpful?

Comment: @AhsanNajam that route passes in various middlewares. `'auth:sanctum', 'verified', 'cors'` can be anyone error.

Comment: @francisco here are those middlewares.
https://imgur.com/a/LgyMcsF

Comment: @AhsanNajam if dd in `SCRFController` means it passes all `middlewares`.